# Is it possible to disable the 'Block Placed' message when using tellraw /setblock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a `/tellraw` shop but to activate command blocks I want to use `/setblock` command when clicked on a text. Is it possible to disable "Block placed" text showing up?

[image: Entering the command into Minecraft]

[image: The 'Block Placed' message]

Comment: Try doing `/gamerule sendCommandFeedback`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No chatoutput in tellraw onClick Event](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238642/no-chatoutput-in-tellraw-onclick-event)

Comment: @pppery Shouldn't the dupe closure be the other way around? The older question and accepted answer here are currently more highly upvoted (2 and 3 votes) than the newer question and only answer (0 and 1 votes) in the [question you linked to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238642/no-chatoutput-in-tellraw-onclick-event). This indicates to me that this question and answer are of higher quality than the other one. This question also currently has 1994 views compared to other question's 462 views — people are more likely to see this question instead of the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the white texts do

```
/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false
```

This will make the white texts not show up.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

Comment: Both of them will work