# No chatoutput in tellraw onClick Event

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm using a `/tellraw` command to display some kind of menu to the player.
How can I react to the clickEvent without posting something in the chat?
When I try using the scoreboard, I get an output in my chat like this
`Set score of <objective> for player <playername> to <value>`. The same thing happens, when trying `/setblock`, `/entitydata` or `/trigger` Is there any way, I can execute a command which commandblocks can detect without writing a success/fail message in the chat?

the only commands without a "real" response message I found were `/say`, `/tell` and `/tellraw`. But all of these are impossible to detect(also, they write something else in the chat).

Comment: Is part of the problem that command blocks are outputting stuff to the chat?  That's solvable with disabling a game rule, something like `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false`.  I think that's what it is, but you can use tab complete to be sure.

Comment: no, i always set that rule when creating my world. Otherwise, the chat would be useless with all the fill clocks running.
The problem is, when the player executes a command by clicking in a `/tellraw` text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that when using `/trigger` (which you should for JSON if you want non-OPs to be able to use the menu) only players in creative will see the "Trigger NAME changed with set 1" message.

If your players are in creative mode and you don't want them to see the message, then you can turn command feedback off via the gamerule:

```
/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false
```