# Hiding Trigger Updates from Chat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have set up a system where the player can update their scoreboard via the tellRaw command using triggers. However, whenever the player clicks on a clickEvent in the chat, the following message appears.

Trigger [nameoftrigger] (set value to #).

Is there any way I can stop this message from appearing in the chat? I don't really want the player to know what is happening "behind the curtain."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable the 'Block Placed' message when using tellraw /setblock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204790/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-block-placed-message-when-using-tellraw-setbloc)

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed!