# How to hide "No items were found on player [ign]" message in chat when using Citizens NPC /clear command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm building a game for an event in about a month or so and I'm having different kits being given by NPCs (I'm new to event/game making so I'm doing the best I can lol if there's a better way to do this let me know), and the `/clear` command used to ensure inventories are cleared before giving the kit they choose when they right-click on an NPC does not clear their armor slots nor offhand, so I have compensated by doing a lot of different `/clear` commands for every item in the kits (ex: `/npc cmd add -o minecraft:clear @s iron_axe`, `/npc cmd add -o minecraft:clear @s crossbow`, and so on) which seems to be working so far.

However, when they first right-click the NPC it spams opped  users with about 15 messages of "No items were found on player [ing]." Is there a way to stop these commands from being sent when the clear command is used? When like 10 players are right-clicking these NPCs it is extremely spamm-y and I've tried a million commands and don't know if it's possible.

I've also never asked a forum question before so if I messed up somewhere tell me <3

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! It sounds like you're on a Bukkit/Spigot server, correct?

Comment: Yes (I think). I'm using Paper 1.16.4 and I know it supports Spigot and Bukkit but idk if its officially a Spigot Bukkit server haha (Hella new to this lmao)

Comment: Cool. Paper is a technically a Spigot server since it's just a fork with some optimizations.

Comment: Oh cool thanks! 

Do you have any ideas regarding removing the clear command? I keep messing around with it and I think I might be out of luck

Comment: Not really, sorry. Been a while since I last touched Minecraft.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable the 'Block Placed' message when using tellraw /setblock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204790/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-block-placed-message-when-using-tellraw-setbloc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false
```