# How can I prevent a command block from saying a command was completed? (Like "Located player") Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I enter the /testfor command, and a player stands on the area the command block is detecting, a chat message appears saying "found MarioTimeWhoa". This didn't used to happen. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide "No items were found on player \[ign\]" message in chat when using Citizens NPC /clear command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378008/how-to-hide-no-items-were-found-on-player-ign-message-in-chat-when-using-cit)

Comment: The version for that duplicate does say java, but the accepted answer's command is the exact same in both versions.

Comment: @Penguin That question involves mods, but the answer is still the same. I would rather use [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/204790/250180) as the duplicate target instead.

Comment: yeah thats better

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You simply have to type /gamerule commandblockoutput false