# How to disable command message in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands

How to disable this messages?         [image: example:]

(btw i have gamerule commandBlockOutput set to false)

Comment: Welcome to arqade.se! Take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance. You should also add a tag to indicate if you're using bedrock (consoles version) or java edition, as the answer might differ.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to disable the 'Block Placed' message when using tellraw /setblock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204790/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-block-placed-message-when-using-tellraw-setbloc)

Comment: @Tacoタコス I fear that's a duplicate based on the answer, and not on both questions.

Comment: @Joachim in essence, the question is the same too; both questions seek to remove the feedback from commands, outside of, the command block output rule.

Comment: @Tacoタコス Ah, okay, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `setcommandfeedback` to `false`. This is technically not the `commandblockoutput` - just a feedback.

Complete command:

```
/gamerule sendcommandfeedback false
```

Comment: Was about to say welcome to arqade.se, but seems like you're already here for some time now ^^ Don't forget to take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) for the little badge ;) Also, does your answer work for both java and bedrock editions? OP hasn't specified yet which version he's using, so having an answer that answers both sides would be great.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this command works on both - Minecraft Bedrock and Java.

Comment: @Nogard No, this command does not work on Java Edition.