# How to stop the killed entities message in Minecraft Java using a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on one of my Minecraft maps and I set up a repeating command block to kill the slimes but in the chat, it just says it killed entities repeatedly and I think that would annoy the people playing.

Does anybody have any ides of what command block and what command I need to do to prevent the commands from being annoying (filling up screen)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable the 'Block Placed' message when using tellraw /setblock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204790/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-block-placed-message-when-using-tellraw-setbloc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple to solve:

- Go into your settings
- From here, go to the chat settings
- From this menu, you can toggle on and off the chat commands as and when you see fit
- Once it is off, no commands will show up in the group chat

If you want to use commands then use this:

> `/gamerule commandblockoutput false`